# Is it possible to parse a string with scope variables angularjs ?

Tags: angularjs

I want to evaluate a string in the form of `"my name is {{name}}"` where `name` is present in the current scope (same way angular does for html content).

This should be simple but i haven't managed to achieve that with `eval` nor `compile`.

[JSBIN example](http://jsbin.com/qilideso/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`$interpolate`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24interpolate) service, like:

```
console.log("using $interpolate: " + $interpolate("'" + s + "'")(scope));
```

> Compiles a string with markup into an interpolation function. This
>   service is used by the HTML $compile service for data binding.

Comment: Thanks man - I was not familiar with this service. It's exactly what i was looking for.